# How to set up an asp.net web site in a subfolder of another web site while still being able to use user controls?

Tags: iis-6, rewrite

I have this scenario:

Website1 (site1.com)
Website2 (site2.com)

In IIS 6.0 site1.com is set up as a web site.  There is a subfolder in site1.com called site2 that I want to use to serve up site2 content.

However, I still want to be able to use usercontrols that are in site1 in site2.  So I think I want site2 to still be part of site1's application?  Or would it be recommended to make site2 an application?  But, then I believe they can't share user controls as easily?

In addition, when a user goes to http://site2.com I want them to see the content of http://site1.com/site2, but I want the address to remain http://site2.com as if the site2 folder is the root.  I don't want something like http://site1.com/site2 or even http://site2.com/site2

Is this possible?  I have found many posts saying I can do this using url rewrites with IIS7 any maybe the same idea can be applied to IIS 6 but I haven't found anything on how exactly to do this in IIS 6.

edit: Is it as simple as setting up some kind of url rewrite so that requests to http://www.site2.com/ map to http://www.site2.com/site2?